# Diagnosing the "too many math alphabets" error

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, kpfonts

I recently hit up against TeX's "too many math alphabets" error. I'm trying to diagnose what is using up my math alphabets, as I can't work out where they are going. Of course, I could just start commenting out sections, but given that this document is 100 pages long, that could take a *long* time.

I'd like to know what packages might be loading math alphabets, and what things count as being from different math alphabets.

My document compiles if I replace

```
\DeclareFontFamily{OT1}{pzc}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{pzc}{m}{it}%
              {<-> s * [1.2] pzcmi7t}{}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathpzc}{OT1}{pzc}%
                                 {m}{it}
```

with

```
\let\mathpzc\mathcal
```

but the following compiles without complaint:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[matha]{mathabx}
\DeclareFontFamily{OT1}{pzc}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{pzc}{m}{it}%
              {<-> s * [1.2] pzcmi7t}{}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathpzc}{OT1}{pzc}%
                                 {m}{it}

\begin{document}
$X \mathbf{X}\mathbb{X}\vDash\mathpzc{X}\alpha\displaystyle\sum \subset \top\mathcal{X}$
\end{document}
```

This document includes (as far as I can tell) all the kinds of math alphabets I took myself to be using. So I am missing something. Something else is using extra math alphabets and I'm not sure how to work out what. What other things count as being different alphabets? What else loads math alphabets?

---

Here's something weird. I do this with a version of my main file and I get this:

```
(0:~jkpmn7t at 12.0pt)
(1:~jkpmi at 12.0pt)
(2:~jkpsy at 12.0pt)
(3:~jkpex at 12.0pt)
(4:~jkpmia at 12.0pt)
(5:~msam10 at 12.0pt)
(6:~msbm10 at 12.0pt)
(7:~jkpsyc at 12.0pt)
(8:~jkpexa at 12.0pt)
(9:~lasy10 at 12.0pt)
(10:~cmex10 at 12.0pt)
(11:~jkpssmn7t at 12.0pt)
(12:~jkpttmn7t at 12.0pt)
(13:~jkpbn7t at 12.0pt)
(14:~jkpsyd at 12.0pt)
(15:~jkpmn7t at 12.0pt)
```

Note that `0` and `15` appear to be the same font…

#### Edit

[I asked a followup question to this one.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40874/kpfonts-siunitx-and-math-alphabets)

Comment: Weirdly, `\let\mathcal\mathpzc` doesn't seem to work…

Comment: When you load the `kpfonts` package, the `amsmath` package is loaded by default -- a setting that can be overridden by loading the package with the `noamsmath` option set. In order not to load any of kpfonts' own math alphabets, you should specify the option `nomath`.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for that. Although in this case, that's not going to help, since I want `amsmath` and I do want to use `kpfonts` math fonts. I'm just trying to work out why there are so many of them!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Math alphabets are loaded "on demand"; so, your `\let\mathpzc\mathcal` doesn't cause LaTeX to allocate a new math alphabet, since the meaning assigned with `\DeclareMathAlphabet` is forgotten (and the math alphabet has not yet been assigned a "math group").

However, once a math alphabet has been used in a formula, its association to a math group is permanent (the actual font will be recomputed based on the current font size).

You can see what math groups are allocated at a particular spot in the document with `\PrintMathFonts` defined as

```
\newcommand{\PrintMathFonts}{%
  \count255=0
  \loop\ifnum\count255<16
    (\the\count255:~\fontname\textfont\count255)
    \advance\count255 by 1
 \repeat}
```

There are only 16 math groups available (the limit is raised by XeTeX and LuaTeX, but one has to change the allocating macros). If I use it immediately after `\begin{document}` I get

> (0: nullfont) (1: nullfont) (2: nullfont) (3: nullfont) (4: nullfont) (5: nullfont) (6: nullfont) (7: nullfont) (8: nullfont) (9: nullfont) (10: nullfont) (11: nullfont) (12: nullfont) (13: nullfont) (14: nullfont) (15: nullfont)

After a trivial formula, `$a$`, I get

> (0: jkpmn7t) (1: jkpmi) (2: jkpsy) (3: jkpex) (4: jkpmia) (5: jkpsya) (6: jkpsyb) (7: jkpsyc) (8: jkpexa) (9: matha10) (10: nullfont) (11: nullfont) (12: nullfont) (13: nullfont) (14: nullfont) (15: nullfont)

After the big formula I get

> (0: jkpmn7t) (1: jkpmi) (2: jkpsy) (3: jkpex) (4: jkpmia) (5: jkpsya) (6: jkpsyb) (7: jkpsyc) (8: jkpexa) (9: matha10) (10: jkpbn7t) (11: pzcmi7t at 11.99997pt) (12: nullfont) (13: nullfont) (14: nullfont) (15: nullfont)

If I also add the formula `$\mathsf{A}$`, I get

> (0: jkpmn7t) (1: jkpmi) (2: jkpsy) (3: jkpex) (4: jkpmia) (5: jkpsya) (6: jkpsyb) (7: jkpsyc) (8: jkpexa) (9: matha10) (10: jkpbn7t) (11: pzcmi7t at 11.99997pt) (12: jkpssmn7t) (13: nullfont) (14: nullfont) (15: nullfont)

Note that some math groups are allocated as soon as a formula is typeset, others aren't (they correspond to math alphabets as opposed to math symbol fonts).

So you see that 10 math groups are already allocated, so you are free to use only up to 6 different math alphabets that don't use letters from the symbol fonts already available (look for `\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet` in `fntguide.pdf`).

## EDIT

A variant of the code above will show in the log file the list, together with the font's symbolic name:

```
\newcommand{\PrintMathFonts}{%
  \typeout{*** Math fonts list ***}
  \count255=0
  \loop\ifnum\count255<16
    \typeout{(\the\count255: \the\textfont\count255 = \fontname\textfont\count255)}
    \advance\count255 by 1
  \repeat
  \typeout{***}}
```

For example, what's printed after the big formula is

```
*** Math fonts list ***
(0: \OT1/jkp/m/n/10 = jkpmn7t)
(1: \OML/jkp/m/it/10 = jkpmi)
(2: \OMS/jkp/m/n/10 = jkpsy)
(3: \OMX/jkp/m/n/10 = jkpex)
(4: \U/jkpmia/m/it/10 = jkpmia)
(5: \U/jkpsya/m/n/10 = jkpsya)
(6: \U/jkpsyb/m/n/10 = jkpsyb)
(7: \U/jkpsyc/m/n/10 = jkpsyc)
(8: \U/jkpexa/m/n/10 = jkpexa)
(9: \U/matha/m/n/10 = matha10)
(10: \OT1/jkp/b/n/10 = jkpbn7t)
(11: \OT1/pzc/m/it/10 = pzcmi7t at 11.99997pt)
(12: \nullfont = nullfont)
(13: \nullfont = nullfont)
(14: \nullfont = nullfont)
(15: \nullfont = nullfont)
***
```

There's no "global registry", I'm afraid, so you have to sort out the fonts according to the packages you're using. Look for the commands

```
\DeclareSymbolFont
\DeclareMathAlphabet
```

The first command declares a math group that is always allocated; the second one causes the math group to be allocated on demand, as said before. For example, the entry

```
(10: \OT1/jkp/b/n/10= jkpbn7t)
```

is caused by `\mathbf` and in `kpfonts.sty` you can find a line

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbf}{OT1}{jkp\kp@famillem\kp@fligm\kp@stylem}{b}{n}
```

that defines it.

Comment: How can I find out what, for example `jkpmn7t` is and where it is used?

Comment: I use it immediately after `\begin{document}` I get 13 used already…

Comment: @Seamus Not with that preamble.

Comment: No not with that preamble. But I'm confused as to what could cause alphabets to be used up before anything's been written to the file!

Comment: @Seamus It's impossible to tell without seeing a MWE exhibiting the problem. It's highly possible that some definition in the preamble builds a box with math in it, so the math groups for `\DeclareSymbolFont` are allocated before `\begin{document}`. In general, they are allocated the first time LaTeX has to build a formula.

Comment: I see. (I'm not giving a MWE, because I can't make one. Like I said this is a huge document. I'm asking for hints on how to diagnose the problem.)

Comment: @Seamus the "Too many math alphabets" error will be issued after using one of them when all math groups are allocated. Look at the formulas before the error, using `\PrintMathFonts` at appropriate spots.

Comment: I think your `\PrintMathFonts` trick is great and answers this vague question as asked. I'll ask a more specific follow up.

Comment: I mention your `\PrintMathFonts` trick in my [blog](http://www.seamusbradley.net/blog/blog/2012/02/20/a-neat-trick-for-finding-whats-using-your-math-fonts/)