# kpfonts, siunitx and math alphabets

Tags: math-mode, siunitx, kpfonts

This is a follow up question to this [rather vague one.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40757/diagnosing-the-too-many-math-alphabets-error) The problem is trying to work out where my 16 math alphabets are going. In using `egreg`'s answer to the previous question I have diagnosed something. So check out this madness:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kpfonts}

\newcommand{\PrintMathFonts}[1]{%
  \count255=0
  \loop\ifnum\count255<16
    \typeout{#1 (\the\count255: \fontname\textfont\count255)}
    \advance\count255 by 1
 \repeat}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\PrintMathFonts{Initial}
\SI{10}{\celsius}
$X$
\PrintMathFonts{Final}
X
\end{document}
```

This prints out what math alphabets have been allocated at various points. Here's the relevant part of the log file:

```
Initial (0: jkpmn7t)
Initial (1: jkpmi)
Initial (2: jkpsy)
Initial (3: jkpex)
Initial (4: jkpmia)
Initial (5: jkpsya)
Initial (6: jkpsyb)
Initial (7: jkpsyc)
Initial (8: jkpexa)
Initial (9: jkpssmn7t)
Initial (10: jkpttmn7t)
Initial (11: nullfont)
Initial (12: nullfont)
Initial (13: nullfont)
Initial (14: nullfont)
Initial (15: nullfont)
Final (0: jkpmn7t)
Final (1: jkpmi)
Final (2: jkpsy)
Final (3: jkpex)
Final (4: jkpmia)
Final (5: jkpsya)
Final (6: jkpsyb)
Final (7: jkpsyc)
Final (8: jkpexa)
Final (9: jkpssmn7t)
Final (10: jkpttmn7t)
Final (11: jkpmn7t)
Final (12: nullfont)
Final (13: nullfont)
Final (14: nullfont)
Final (15: nullfont)
```

So, before I have typed *anything at all* TWELVE of my sixteen fonts are already used. `siunitx` appears to cause the math alphabets to be used before anything is written. OK. That's fine, I'll leave that aside for now. What's doubly weird is that once I've used `\SI` to typeset so units, another alphabet is used up (position 11). What's odd about this is that it's the same font as position 0. Why is this? Isn't this a waste? Can I don something about it?

Using standard computer modern means only 6 alphabets are used up at `Initial` and that's the same as at `Final`. Using `fouriernc` seems to cause the same problem (duplicate font) as with `kpfonts`. However, fewer fonts are used up.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The packages `kpfonts`, `fourier` and `fouriernc` all say

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathrm}{<enc>}{<family>}{<weight>}{<shape>}
```

instead of the correct

```
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathrm}{operators}
```

that's recommended by `fntguide.pdf`; this causes LaTeX to load an extra font when something with `\mathrm` is typeset (for example a unit with `\SI`). To avoid this, issue the latter command after loading the font package.

Comment: after loading the font package, _and before loading `siunitx`_ right?

Comment: @Seamus Before or after siunitx should be irrelevant.

Answer (score 5):

I can explain the `siunitx` part, if not the entire situation. In order to be able to tell which math font is in use, at the start of the document there is a need to force some math typesetting. This is done using more or less

```
\setbox\tempbox=\hbox{\ensuremath{\mathsf{\global\chardef\siunitxmathsf=\fam}}}
\setbox\tempbox=\hbox{\ensuremath{\mathtt{\global\chardef\siunitxmathtt=\fam}}}
```

which records the family number for the sanserif and monospaced math fonts for later use.

The second thing to know is that `siunitx` uses `\mathrm` to typet upright material in math (as standard). If you try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kpfonts}

\newcommand{\PrintMathFonts}[1]{%
  \count255=0
  \loop\ifnum\count255<16
    \typeout{#1 (\the\count255: \fontname\textfont\count255)}
    \advance\count255 by 1
 \repeat}

\begin{document}
\PrintMathFonts{Initial}
$\mathrm{a}$
\PrintMathFonts{Final}
\end{document}
```

you will see that this also uses an 'extra' font. This does not happen with other math font packages, and so presumably is a bug/'feature' of `kpfonts`.

Comment: What about the problem of loading the same font twice? That happened with `fouriernc` as well as `kpfonts` though not with computer modern.