# limit math alphabets created by siunitx

Tags: siunitx

As pointed out in response to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40874/kpfonts-siunitx-and-math-alphabets) the package `siunitx` allocates multiple math alphabets. Is it possible to request that some not be allocated? I, for one, don't plan to use `\mathtt`, so it would be nice if `\RequirePackage[nott]{siunitx}`, or some such would do that for me. Of course maybe I overlooked something in the documentation?

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible with the current version of `siunitx`, but I agree that the math alphabets should only be loaded on demand.

Comment: are they actually allocated?  normally latex math alphabets are just declared but only allocated to one of the 16 math families if they are used, but I'v enot checked the siunitx code

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Yes, they are allocated. The question referenced above in my original posting makes this clear. Further down that page, Joseph Wright (author of `siunitx`) says, “In order to be able to tell which math font is in use, at the start of the document there is a need to force some math typesetting.”