# Too many math alphabets - How to make a M(not)WE?

Tags: fonts

Let's consider the two files below (they come from one of my very modest LaTeX projects).

1. [tnsmath-doc[fr].tex](https://github.com/typensee-latex/tnsmath/blob/master/tnsmath/tnsmath-doc%5Bfr%5D.tex)
2. [tnsmath.sty](https://github.com/typensee-latex/tnsmath/blob/master/tnsmath/tnsmath.sty)

The use of `latex -shell-escape tnsmath-doc\[fr\].tex` with these two files gives me the following error.

```
! LaTeX Error: Too many math alphabets used in version normal.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.1 $\setalge{A}
                $ ,
```

I know that I have to use things like in the code above to avoid that kind of error (the lines of the example are inside `tnsmath.sty`).

```
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{
  <-5.5> mathb5
  <5.5-6.5> mathb6
  <6.5-7.5> mathb7
  <7.5-8.5> mathb8
  <8.5-9.5> mathb9
  <9.5-11> mathb10
  <11-> mathb12
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathb}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\tnslog@leftleftharpoons}  {3}{mathb}{"D8}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\tnslog@rightrightharpoons}{3}{mathb}{"D9}
```

I would like to do the same thing everywhere that is needed but I have to make first a M(not)WE from my huge TEX file such as to test the usefulness of my changes.

Can someone help me?

Comment: is this helping you? <https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3676/too-many-math-alphabets-error?rq=1>

Comment: Not really.....

Comment: @campa I know that. When I use `\DeclareMathSymbol`, is it considered as a whole font loading? If it is, is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: @campa So sad... I will play a little with `\usefont` to see if it is acceptable for me.

Comment: @campa Is there an easy way to list the fonts used? This could help me to see if I can do some compromises.

Comment: You might want to read https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40757/82917

Comment: Thanks. The macro `\PrintMathFonts` is very useful.

Comment: As I commented elsewhere, if you can use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, `unicode-math` does not have this problem.

Comment: `\DeclareMathSymbol` itself doesn't use a family but `\DeclareSymbolFont`  uses one. You really have not shown enough code to allow anyone to help but do you really need more than 16 font families in a single math exprerssion? or as Davislor says you can use luatex or xetex which allow 256 rather than 16.

Comment: please make a self contained example that shows the problem and add to the question. It is unreasonable to ask people to use `--shell-escape` which is presumably only used for minted which will be unrelated to math fonts. You should be able to make a far simpler example